# Google Interview : Find the maximum sum of a polygon

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, matrix-multiplication

Given a polygon with `N` vertexes and `N` edges. There is an int number(could be negative) on every vertex and an operation in set `(*,+)` on every edge. Every time, we remove an edge E from the polygon, merge the two vertexes linked by the edge `(V1,V2)` to a new vertex with value: `V1 op(E) V2`. The last case would be two vertexes with two edges, the result is the bigger one.

Return the max result value can be gotten from a given polygon.

For the last case we might not need two merge as the other number could be negative, so in that case we would just return the larger number.

How I am approaching the problem:

```
 p[i,j] denotes the maximum value we can obtain by merging nodes from labelled i to j.
 p[i,i] = v[i] -- base case
 p[i,j] = p[i,k] operator in between p[k+1,j] , for k between i to j-1.
and then p[0,n] will be my answer.
Second point , i will have to start from all the vertices and do the same as above as this will be cyclic n vertices n edges.
The time complexity for this is n^3 *n i.e n^4 .
```

Can i do better then this ?

Comment: i don't know why some same set of people are voting against my problems everyday. Do you guys have any personal grudge , did i not accept your answer sometime or so ? what is too localized or off topic in this . it is an algorithm problem i have written my approach , i am looking for a more optimized method if exist, i have been very frank that it is a Google interview problem , what else people want who vote to close

Comment: Maybe some folks think it's spoiling the interview for future candidates? I do wish folks would give reasons for down votes etc.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401923/algorithm-for-polygon-with-weight-on-vertices-and-operations-on-edges/14403885#14403885

Comment: there is no solution there still

Comment: I have added a solution to your problem, there are more efficient solutions but they are far more complicated, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have identified (tagged) correctly, this indeed is very similar to the matrix multiplication problem (in what order do I multiply matrixes in order to do it quickly).

This can be solved polynomially using a dynamic algorithm.

I'm going to instead solve a similar, more classic (and identical) problem, given a formula with numbers, addition and multiplications, what way of parenthesizing it gives the maximal value, for example 
`6+1 * 2` becomes `(6+1)*2` which is more than `6+(1*2)`.

Let us denote our input `a1 to an` real numbers and o(1),...o(n-1) either `*` or `+`. Our approach will work as follows, we will observe the subproblem F(i,j) which represents the maximal formula (after parenthasizing) for a1,...aj. We will create a table of such subproblems and observe that F(1,n) is exactly the result we were looking for.

Define

```
F(i,j)

 - If i>j return 0 //no sub-formula of negative length
 - If i=j return ai // the maximal formula for one number is the number
 - If i<j return the maximal value for all m between i (including) and j (not included) of:
     F(i,m) (o(m)) F(m+1,j) //check all places for possible parenthasis insertion
```

This goes through all possible options. TProof of correctness is done by induction on the size n=j-i and is pretty trivial.

**Lets go through runtime analysis:**

If we do not save the values dynamically for smaller subproblems this runs pretty slow, however we can make this algorithm perform relatively fast in `O(n^3)`

We create a n*n table T in which the cell at index i,j contains F(i,j) filling F(i,i) and F(i,j) for j smaller than i is done in O(1) for each cell since we can calculate these values directly, then we go diagonally and fill F(i+1,i+1) (which we can do quickly since we already know all the previous values in the recursive formula), we repeat this n times for n diagonals (all the diagonals in the table really) and filling each cell takes (O(n)), since each cell has O(n) cells we fill each diagonals in O(n^2) meaning we fill all the table in O(n^3). After filling the table we obviously know F(1,n) which is the solution to your problem.

[image: The order that we fill our table]

**Now back to your problem**

If you translate the polygon into `n` different formulas (one for starting at each vertex) and run the algorithm for formula values on it, you get exactly the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reduce the need for a brute force search. For example: if there is a chain of

```
x + y + z
```

You can replace it with a single vertex whose value is the sum, you can't do better than that. You need to do the multiplying after the addition when you're dealing with +ve integers. So if it's all positive then simply reduce all + chains and then mutliply.

So that leaves the cases where there are -ve numbers. Seems to me that the strategy for a single -ve number is pretty obvious, for two -ve numbers there are a few cases (remembering that - x - is positive) and for more than 2 -ve numbers it seems to get tricky :-)